# Какую бесплатную базу данных использовать для хранения файлов в данном случае?

Tags: база-данных

Планируется организовывать "разовые" очереди печати между клиентами... Среднее количество клиентов - несколько сотен, средний размер файлов - несколько мегабайт (иногда в разы больше...). Какую бесплатную базу данных для данной задачи лучше использовать?

Comment: Хранить файлы в базе данных — плохая идея. Файлы лучше хранить в файлах.

Comment: Можно же хранить пути к файлам, а не сами файлы

Comment: @КириллМалышев лично я так и делаю.

Answer (score 0):

Как вам правильно указал Андрей. Хранить файлы только для хранения не самая хорошая идея. Ну раз все же если вы решили хранить то используйте [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/).

Comment: Почему, например, не MySQL?

Comment: Потому что это моя рекомендация. Чисто субъективно.

Comment: С настройками по умолчанию, на Windows или Linux?

Comment: Разницы нет на ваше усмотрение. Сервер ваш решать также вам. Я лишь рекомендую